# Best way to cause rerender on hook object update

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

Say I have a functional component like this:

```
function App(){

  const [obj, setObj] = useState({arr:[1,2,3,4,5]})

  const swap = (a,b)=>{
    const updatedArr = Object.assign(
      obj.arr,
      {
        [a.toString()]:obj.arr[b],
        [b.toString()]:obj.arr[a]
      }
    )
    setObj(
      Object.assign(
        obj,
        {arr:updatedArr}
      )
    )
  };

  const buttonAction = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    swap(0,4)
  }

  return <div>
    <button onClick = {buttonAction}>swap</button>
    <ul>
    {
      obj.arr.map(
        item=>{return <li key={item.toString()}>{item}</li>}
        )
    }
    </ul>
  </div>
}
```

The 'swap' button causes the `swap` function to swap the first and last elements of the array. When I inspect this in developer tools this is in fact what happens:

Before function: 
[image: object before function]

After function: 
[image: object after function]

It does not, however, cause a rerender, so the list stays the same in the view.

I can force a rerender by changing the swap function to contain the following:

```
const newObj = Object.assign(
    obj,
    {arr:updatedArr}
  )
setObj(
  Object.assign(
    {},
    newObj
  )
)
```

So by assigning the updated object to a new one I can force a rerender. Is this the best way to do this? Or is there a better way to get the component to rerender when an object in a hook changes?

UPDATE: before someone asks me what I mean by 'better', I mean something that's more 'React-y', that is in keeping with the intentions of the people who designed the framework, who certainly must have anticipated a situation like this.

Comment: What happens if you use the item index as a key for <li> rather than the item value?

Comment: @Remeus I did try that but it doesn't change anything

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you are modifying state directly and that is causing the update to not trigger the render.

```
setObj(
    Object.assign(
        obj,
        {arr:updatedArr}
    )
)
```

`Object.assign` is changing the obj variable (your state) directly with the new ordered arr. Then `setObj` is taking this obj and assigning it to itself - At this point react is comparing the objects (with `Object.is`) to decide if a render is necessary. Since it's the exact same object, it will not re-render.

In your working update, you are assigning to a new object, so react will render.

That, said, the react-y way to do it would be to not modify the state directly (essentially what you are doing with a slight modification)

```
const swap = (a,b)=>{
    const updatedArr = Object.assign(
        [...obj.arr],
        {
            [a.toString()]:obj.arr[b],
            [b.toString()]:obj.arr[a]
        }
    )
    setObj(
        Object.assign(
            {},
            obj,
            {arr:updatedArr}
        )
    )
};
```

Comment: Yeah, I think your diagnosis is correct; it is what I was thinking. If that's the case then the only way around it really is to copy it to a new object. I'll wait a day or two and if no one else has any better idea I'll mark this as the solution.